# MOV file directly from camera error while encoding in Azure Media Services

Tags: azure

I'm trying to upload & convert a MOV file (GSpot says it's Motion JPEG video codec) just as it's off the camera (Panasonic LX3), however I get the following error with the encoding job:

nb:jid:UUID:f3855e24-5993-6d4c-a1c6-12079b73fb04 My encoding job Error 8/19/2012 11:22:13 PM 00:00:12.4880000

My encoding task Error

Apple QuickTime must be installed in order to playback Apple Quicktime files.

Can I do something around this ? I have to build a website where users will upload their movies, and this MOV format should be very common as it's directly from the camera.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

At the moment MOV does not seem to be a valid import format. You can see the whole list here: [Media Encoder Import Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973634). Note that Windows Azure Media Services is still in preview, the list of supported formats might change in the final version of the product.

Comment: I've also tried with a MOV from an iPhone, that one did convert successfully.

Comment: It seems that on iPhone this is MP4 (even though the extension is MOV). See that last comment in this thread: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2629714?start=0&tstart=0